# RigidbodyController background stutter (Am I moving my Rigidbody controller correctly?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm working on a playercontroller, very basic and am encountering loads of stutter when using the rigidbody player. I also have a character controller player which runs very smooth, both tests are at high fps 600 ish (v-sync turned off). I am using the freelook camera of unity's cinemachine in both cases and set the CinemachineBrain update mode to fixed for the Rigidbody scene. I have tried turning on Interpolation on the Rigidbody and chaging the FixedUpdateTimestep (which I try to avoid), but I am wondering if it has anything to do with the way I move my Rigidbody? Below is a video to show the issues, make sure to watch it fullscreen and pay attention to the blockstairs (Incase it's unclear the red player is Rigidbody based and the green one uses a CharacterController component). You can see a huge difference in smoothes between the scenes.

My Rigidbody movement code (Very simple);

```cs
void Update()
{
    _isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(_groundChecker.position, GroundDistance, Ground, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);

    _inputs = Vector3.zero;
    _inputs.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    _inputs.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    if (_inputs != Vector3.zero)
        transform.forward = _inputs;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    _body.MovePosition(_body.position + _inputs * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

[Video showcasing the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kX-CctUHZXg)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to move rigid bodies directly you will need to turn on the kinematic flag for it.  Otherwise all other rigidbody and forces that are applied to it through your movement will affect it and cause jitter or strange behavior.

See this page: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

Comment: I don't believe the players Rigidbody needs to be kinematic, since than it is impossible to collide with other objects. On a side note I did give it a quick test, but without any luck.